# Peer review process for knowledge

Tags: knowledge

We are implemented a knowledge base and have a weird requirement that doesn't seem to work with it. We have a peer review approval process where people review each others work, then publish. However, because these users also have the publish permission, there is nothing enforcing the approval. How can I make this process work?